# Call to a member function count()

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a "Call to a member function count()" error. I have tried various methods to fix this but now I am stuck.

The problem is here:

```
var_dump($data, $field);

if($user->count()) {
   $this->_data = $data->first();
```

Here is my Code:

```
class user {
    private $_db,
    $_data;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance(); 
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';   
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, ' = ', $user));

            var_dump($data, $field);
            if($user->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;    
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === hash::make($password, $this->data()->$salt)) {

                echo 'OK!';

            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }
}
```

```
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;   
    private $_pdo, 
            $_query, 
            $_error = false, 
            $_results, 
            $_count = 0;

            private function __construct()  {
                try {
                    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db').'', ''.Config::get('mysql/username').'', ''.Config::get('mysql/password').'');
            echo 'Connected';

                }   catch(PDOException $e) {
                        die($e->getMessage());  
                }

            }
            public static function getInstance() {
                if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
                        self::$_instance = new DB();    
                }
                return self::$_instance;
            }
            public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
                    $this->_error = false;
                    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                        $x = 1;
                        if(count($params)) {
                            foreach($params as $param) {
                                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                                $x++;   
                            }
                        }
                            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                            } else {
                                $this->_error = true;   
                            }
                    }
                    return $this;
            }

            private function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
                    if(count($where) === 3) {
                        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

                        $field      = $where[0];
                        $operator   = $where[1];
                        $value      = $where[2];

                        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                                return $this;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
            }

            public function get($table, $where) {
                return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
            }

            public function delete($table, $where) {
                return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
            }

            public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {

                        $keys = array_keys($fields);
                        $values = '';
                        $x = 1;

                        foreach($fields as $field) {
                                $values .= '?';
                                if($x < count($fields)) {
                                    $values .= ', ';    
                                }
                            $x++;
                        }


                        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`". implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

                        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                                return true;
                        }

                return false;
            }

            public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
                $set = '';  
                $x = 1;

                foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
                    $set .= "{$name} = ?";
                    if($x < count($fields)) {
                        $set .= ', ';
                    }
                    $x++;
                }


                $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id ={$id}";

                if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                    return true;    
                }
                return false;
            }

            public function results() {
                return $this->_results; 
            }

            public function first() {
                return $this->_results[0];
            }

            public function error() {
                return $this->_error;
            }

            public function count() {
                return $this->_count;   
            }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
*You are using the wrong operator in your call to $this->_db->get.  You pass in ' = ' but the acceptable operator is '=' (no spaces).  This combined with the suggestions below will fix your problem.*

looks like you need `$data->count()` not `$user->count()`

```
public function find($user = null) {
    if($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';   
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if($data && $data->count() > 0) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You should work on better variable names, you use $user in several places where the actual value is NOT a user object.

`public function find($user = null) {`

This is a number or string, instead try

`public function find($queryParam = null) {`

`$user = $this->find($username);`

This is a boolean, instead try

`$userFound = $this->find($username)'`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but ($data->count()) didn't work either.$data is returning false in my variable dump. Still confused. I will try these other suggestions also.

Comment: @RubiRed I've updated my answer, if $success is false, your query is not executing correctly in which case you will need to debug it further.

Comment: @RubiRed I've looked at this again and found that you are using the wrong operator in your get query, see the EDIT to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your `query` method updates the property `$_count` with the count of the last query executed. You have a public method to access this property; `count()`. Your database class object is held in the property `_db`. Therefore, we can do the following;

```
if($this->_db->count()) {
   $this->_data = $data->first();
```

Comment: In this case, this is a bad answer because this will return the count of the last run query.  The query in question is never run because the wrong operator is used.  [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26266500/2464634)

Answer (score -2):

If this code:

```
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
```

indicates that `$user` can sometimes be something OTHER than an object, why are you unconditionally doing

```
        if($user->count()) {
```

which would REQUIRE that `$user` is always an object?

Comment: $user is the (poorly) named method parameter, not the same object ($this) that find is invoked on.  Also, this is not an answer. Sorry

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong method call. OP has `$user->count()` right afterwards.